# Way to detect deployment status of a ear deployed in Jboss as 7 or latter

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, wildfly, ear

an ear is deployed in a Jboss server (wildfly 11). while deployment is on going if client tries to call any EJB , call will hit the LoginModule.this makes some problem due to the internal design in the application. 
what is the best reliable way to detect the deployment status of a given ear (or the status of the server) programmatically from a class which is a part of that ear(run in the same JVM , in the same ear).

Answer (score 0):

JBoss is providing a CLI API to access management with a Java API (`org.wildfly:wildfly-cli`). CLI offers commands for deployment, undeployment and checking deplyoment status. You can call the [HTTP management API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/The+HTTP+management+API) directly, if you want to.

Doing this from your EAR while it is deployed might be interesting. Perhaps you can install a server side container interceptor with your EJBs. I never tried ...